# время хранение сессий

Tags: php

Нубский вопрос, но я что то совсем запутался

Задача состоит в том, чтоб после закрытия всех вкладок в брузере одного домена ( т.к еще есть поддомены ) , удалять сессию

Индификатор хранится в куки.
Какую настройку нужно сделать?( у меня хостинг и к php ini доступа нет)

Answer (score 0):

Как работает Sission в PHP, вы не спрашивали, поэтому углубляться не буду. Эту информацию можно почерпнуть в интернете. Сессия передаётся с помощью куков, которые очистятся после закрытия браузера, не вкладки. Сессии можно дать время жизни самостоятельно. Если у вас получится получить на сервер запрос, что вкладка была закрыта, вы можете её закончить, но нужно проверить, есть ли ещё вкладки с таким доменом? (Ну эту информацию можно получить, в общем-то, было бы желание). Можно из открытой вкладки делать любой запрос, который будет напоминать серверу, что пользователь ещё активный, и сделать таймаут немного большее секунд чем этот запрос обработается сервером. (Если долго нет вызова со стороны клиента, можно предположить, что пользователь ушел [будет конфликт при быстром открытии/закрытии вкладки!]) А sessionStorage - работает, например, с 11 версии IE.

Comment: Я думаю, что этот вопрос если и можно решить, то только тесно работая с клиентом, с помощью одного сервера, к сожалению, имхо, это не реализовать